# Why doesn't DIV's height apply with percents?

Tags: css

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6axdexfj/

Once in a great while I come across a problem, and when I do I search to find a solution when I can't seem to figure it out myself.

So I'm building a web design app, and thoughout today I been reconstructing it so no garbage css is added in.

Today I added some simple styling to an element and I noticed that if I don't have `position: absolute;` or `fixed` on a standalone div that it's height is not changed when encoded with percent's.

```
.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 244, 85);
}
```

I noticed this years ago and still to this day I don't know why it does that. I always avoid it by applying the following to my body.

```
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Can somebody explain why this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your css and it should work

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that your `body` and `html` container does not have the full height by default, thus your `div` by default will not have full height. To avoid this in the future, use `reset.css` to make your life easy :)

[LINK TO reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css)